# am just to seed my db but am getting an error

Tags: laravel-8

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'category-name' for key 'categories_slug_unique' (SQL: insert into `categories` (`name`, `slug`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (quia rerum, category-name, 2021-06-01 15:27:19, 2021-06-01 15:27:19))

Comment: Please share more details. Is there anything unclear about the error message? What have you tried to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a duplicate entry for unique columns. check your migration file for "->unique" and make sure that every entry to that field is unique.